# How to make a has_one through has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Context:**
I have 2 models `ClinicalSystem` and `TemplateMessage`

**My goal:** is to have `ClinicalSystem` with many `TemplateMessage` but also have multiple has_one realtion with `TemplateMessage` with different namings. e.g:

```
clinical_system.tempalte_messages, clinical_system.reschedule_template_message, clinical_system.cancellation_template_message.
```

How do I structure my associations to achieve that ? I have tried `has_many: through` but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the main `has_many` association and the `has_one` associations separately like below:

```
class ClinicalSystem
  has_many :tempalte_messages
  has_one :reschedule_template_message, -> { CONDITION_FOR_RESCHEDULE }, class_name: TemplateMessage.name
  has_one :cancellation_template_message, -> { CONDITION_FOR_CANCELLATION }, class_name: TemplateMessage.name
end
```

Comment: I do not have any categories or types. That is why it is tricky for me)

Comment: You can still add the conditions easily and add `class_name` while defining the associations. I have updated the answer, please check now.

Comment: It may sound strange but what if it does not have a condition for being different kind of template message? I have tried adding class_name but it does not work too.

Comment: well, if you want to define a subset of `tempalte_messages` as `reschedule` and `cancellation` messages, you need to have some kind of differentiator in the TemplateMessage model. Without it, how exactly will you differentiate?

Comment: We differentiate them by naming but the problem is that for different clinical system naming can be different therefore I cant just put some general regex or something.

Comment: I would suggest you add a `category/type` identifier in your TemplateMessage model so that different kinds of template messages are easily identifiable based on this attribute and you don't run into a big issue in the future even if you are able to find any hacky solution today that works.

Comment: you can add a column `type` to template_messages and define an `enum` in the model with all the types that you have currently and you can add any new type that you need in the future to this list.

Comment: @sanchin-singh I cant add `type` column to template_message since one template_message can be one type for one clinical_system and another type for another clinical_system. So I have to keep it as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `foreign_key` and `class_name`

```
class ClinicalSystem
  has_many :tempalte_messages
  belongs_to :reschedule_template_message, foreign_key: 'reschedule_template_message_id', class_name: 'TemplateMessage'
  belongs_to :cancellation_template_message, foreign_key: 'cancellation_template_message_id', class_name: 'TemplateMessage'
end
```

You will also need to add migration to add foreign_keys `reschedule_template_message_id` and `cancellation_template_message_id`  in the clinical_systems table

Comment: I guess it is a solution for my problem but I have 15 different types of template message for one clinical system therefore I was hoping for more dynamic approach.

Comment: Also, I think you meant I have to add those foreign keys to template_messages not clinical_systems

Comment: I have updated my answer, instead of using has_one you can use `belongs_to`, this will work if you have only these 2 relations, but as per your first comment you have different types of messages, I will see if I can come up with dynamic approach for that